# How to make php array to be a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have file php that send value in array by query to ajax.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM populasi INNER JOIN waktu ON populasi.idWaktu = waktu.id WHERE waktu.jam = $jam";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$points=array();
foreach ($result as $m) {
    $points[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$m[x].', '.$m[y].')';
}
print_r($points);
```

this ajax will receive a value from php file and I want the value to be a javascript array like "var points". Can you help me how to do it ? Thanks

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proses.php",
    data: {
      jam: slider.value,
    },
    success: function(response){
        //example array points
        var points = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(-7.320339, 112.768071),
          new google.maps.LatLng(-7.320233, 112.768446),
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: you can [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the array and receive [json as response from ajax](https://www.lennu.net/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/). Then you can process the array data as you wish

Answer (score 0):

can you please try below code 
The PHP json_encode function translates the data passed to it to a JSON string which can then be output to a JavaScript variable.get response and used to your javascript code

```
<?php  $json_points = json_encode($points); ?>
```

Comment: its work, but the value in the array sent is a string because I don't know how to send it not in string form. I want the value of the array to be like "var points". can you help me how?

Comment: @ i am not get you comment .can you please explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this is to convert data to JSON format in php and pass it to your js code

in your php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM populasi INNER JOIN waktu ON populasi.idWaktu = waktu.id WHERE waktu.jam = $jam";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$result = json_encode($result);
echo($result);
```

in js:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "proses.php",
  data: {jam:slider.value,
  },
  success: function(response){
    response=JSON.parse(response);
    var points=[];
    for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
        var responsePoint=response[i];
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(responsePoint.x, responsePoint.y));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: you also need to set the "Content-Type" header to "application/json" (just before echoing) in order for the client-side to receive it as json (and parse it accordingly) and set `dataType: "json"` in ajax parameters in client-side

Comment: @NikosM. I think if you set Content-Type to json you wont need to run this line in js: `response=JSON.parse(response)`  because it knows the response is JSON and it will parse it automatically.

Comment: exactly which would be best as it is in fact json response and should have the apropriate content-type attached

Comment: I tried it with "console.log(points)" but there is no value in the array. do you know why?

Comment: check your browsers web console. in network tab see whats the response, maybe its empty.

Comment: yes its empty when I check in browser web console. can you tell me why ?

Comment: it might be because your sql query is not returning any results

Comment: I think the query is correct, maybe the way to retrieve the value from the query is wrong. can you explain how?

Comment: Can you run the query and show me what print_r($result) gives back?